# How do I validate my DWR @RemoteMethod input objects?

Tags: spring, validation, dwr, data-transfer-objects

I’m using DWR 3.0.0-rc2 and Spring 3.1.1.RELEASE.  I was wondering if its possible to validate my @DataTransferObject input object using the Spring style “@Valid” (javax.validation.Valid) annotation.  My specific question is, if this is possible and I set up my remote call like so …

```
@RemoteMethod
@Override
public String myRemoteMethod(@Valid final MyDto request)
{
```

how do I test to see if the input object (request) is valid and then throw a corresponding set of errors back to the client?
Thanks, - Dave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a good case to apply some AOP.  One way is to create a `@Before` aspect that inspects the called arguments to see if they are annotated with `@Valid`, and if so trigger the validation for that argument and treat the results.

The code of this aspect would look like this:

```
@Aspect
public class ValidatingAspect {

    Validator validator;

    public ValidatingAspect() {
        Configuration<?> configuration = Validation.byDefaultProvider().configure();
        ValidatorFactory factory = configuration.buildValidatorFactory();
        this.validator = factory.getValidator();    
    }

    @Before("execution(* com.yourpackage..*.*(..))")
    public void validateBefore(JoinPoint jp) throws Throwable {
        Object[] args = jp.getArgs();
        MethodSignature ms = (MethodSignature) jp.getSignature();
        Method m = ms.getMethod();

        Annotation[][] parameterAnnotations = m.getParameterAnnotations();

        for (int i = 0; i < parameterAnnotations.length; i++) {
            Annotation[] annotations = parameterAnnotations[i];
            for (Annotation annotation : annotations) {
                if (annotation.annotationType() == Valid.class) {
                    Set<ConstraintViolation<T>> constraintViolations =  validator.validate(jp.getArgs()[i]); 
                       ... handle validation results ...
                }
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: Hi, THis looks like a promising approach.  How do I apply the aspect to the method in question?

Comment: this can be activated via `<aop:aspectj-autoproxy />`, have a look at this example: http://www.mkyong.com/spring3/spring-aop-aspectj-annotation-example/

Comment: Thanks.  Is the field "validator" a class you created?  Could it automatically handle fields in my request object marked as "@NotNull" (javax.validation.constraints.NotNull) or would I have to create custom logic for validating those kinds of annotations?

Comment: Validator is from the BeanValidation jar, it will detect annotation like `@NotNull` in your Pojo classes and verify them